# Start of a Script from one server to another server

Tags: server, share, volume

I've got a server (raspberry PI 3) which functions  as a webserver.

Additionally, I've got a client (raspberry PI 3) with a camera connected.

I've created a script on the client, which creates an image of the camera and then sends it automatically to a volume share of the server(webserver).
With a simple `<img>` HTML tag I want to show the image on the website.
Now I have to manually start the script, which triggers the camera.
*So my question is:*

**How can I start a script from the server(webserver) which triggers the script from the client automatically?**

My idea was with sshpass. Unfortunately that did not work.

**How would it work via SSH PASS or what else is a useful way?**

Comment: You should ask this question at [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: thank you very much I did it.